# Reliably check network connection type in .Net (windows 7)

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

In .Net (desktop, Win7), is there a canonical way to reliably check the network connection type for whether the active network connection is a mobile connection?

Currently I have this:

```
public bool IsMobileConnectionActive()
{
    if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) return false;

    // PPP & broadband Interfaces
    var broadbandTypes = new[]
    {
            NetworkInterfaceType.Ppp,
            NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp,
            NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp2
        };

    var mobileInterfaces = from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                           where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                           where broadbandTypes.Contains(nic.NetworkInterfaceType)
                           select nic;
    return mobileInterfaces.Any();
}
```

However it seems rather brittle to check for specific network interface types. For example, in .net 4, the types Wwanpp and Wwanpp2 were not available.

Ideally, this check would be provided by the framework somehow...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to struggle to do this reliably given the amount of use-cases for "Mobile" in the current age. For example, the user could be tethered to their smartphone, connected to a 3g/4g Hub device like [this](http://www.o2.co.uk/business/products-and-services/broadband-and-network/pop-up-office) all of which I believe will appear like any other Wifi connection.

It really depends on why you are trying to do this? You could perhaps test the latency on the connection, but again as mobile networks improve this will become less reliable.

Comment: We need to provide a visual indication of which kind of connection is active. It's true that in general this is difficult to solve, but we're in a scenario where we "know" the hardware and the ways users connect to networks, either via mobile broadband or 'real' LAN/Wifi connection.   The hardware is standardized, but still, the problem is that new revisions sometimes get new modems or drivers, reporting new NIC types (e.g. we missed the Wwanpp2 type at first).